# Should we always put validation group

Tags: asp.net, validationgroup

Should we always put validation group even if the page has no more than one validation group or should we wait until there is a need to seperate validation group then we put the validation group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no need to put a validation group if there isn't a need to separate them out.

Answer (score 0):

No, Not necessarily. Like If you want to use ValidationSummary control for the validation controls then you have to use validation group.